# My UFT code cannot identify browser/parent object. Keep getting 'cannot find objects parent'

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am a software automation student and new to programming. I have only been writing code for about a few weeks. The automation tool I'm using is UFT and the language is VB script

When I write scripts in UFT I sometimes come across this error:

---

```
Cannot find the "[ WebList ]" object's parent "[ Browser ]" (class Browser). Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Line (32): "Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebList("html id:=state", "html tag:=SELECT").Select State".
```

---

I know it means UFT cannot identify browser or page. What I don't know is why. I thought I wrote the code correctly. I even added creationtime and title in browser and page to better identify it.

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Here's my entire script. It's short, only 54 lines.

---

Option Explicit

```
Dim MyExcel, MySheet, RowCount, i ,IE, URL, State, PayType, Pay, PayFrequency, MaritalStatus, WithholdingAllowances, AdditionalWithholding, Allowances, AdditionalWithholding2, ActualCheckValue, ExpectedCheckValue, CapturedTaxRate

Set MyExcel = CreateObject ("Excel.Application")

MyExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\PIIT\Documents\Excel Docs\In Class Assigment - 7.xlsx"

Set MySheet = MyExcel.ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets ("Sheet1")

IE = "iexplore.exe"
URL = "suburbancomputer.com/tips_calculator.php"

SystemUtil.CloseProcessByName IE
SystemUtil.Run IE, URL
wait 5

RowCount = MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To RowCount

State = MySheet.Cells(i,"A")
PayType = MySheet.Cells(i,"B")
Pay = MySheet.Cells(i,"C")
PayFrequency = MySheet.Cells(i,"D")
MaritalStatus = MySheet.Cells(i,"E")
WithholdingAllowances = MySheet.Cells(i,"F")
AdditionalWithholding = MySheet.Cells(i,"G")
Allowances = MySheet.Cells(i,"H")
AdditionalWithholding2 = MySheet.Cells(i,"I")
ActualCheckValue = MySheet.Cells(i,"J")

Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebList("html id:=state", "html tag:=SELECT").Select State
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebList("innertext:=Salary Hourly ", "html tag:=SELECT").Select PayType
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebEdit("html id:=salary", "html tag:=INPUT").Set Pay
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebList("html id:=ppy", "html tag:=SELECT").Select PayFrequency
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebList("html id:=fit_marital_status", "html tag:=SELECT").Select MaritalStatus
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebList("html id:=fit_dependent", "html tag:=SELECT").Select WithholdingAllowences
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebEdit("html id:=fit_addon", "html tag:=INPUT").Set AdditionalWithholdings
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebList("html id:=state_dependent", "html tag:=SELECT").Select Allowences
Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebEdit("html id:=state_addon", "html tag:=INPUT").Set AdditionalWithholding2

Browser("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").Page("micclass:=Browser", "CreationTime:=0", "Title:=.*").WebButton("name:=Calculate Paycheck", "class:=nav_button").Click
wait 2

ActualCheckValue = Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").Page("micclass:=Page").WebElement("html tag:=B", "index:=16").GetROProperty("innerhtml")
Print ActualCheckValue
Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").Page("micclass:=Page").Link("html id:=ui-id-3", "innerhtml:=Effective Rate").Click 

CapturedTaxRate = Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").Page("micclass:=Page").WebElement("html tag:=B", "index:=21").GetROProperty("innerhtml")
Print CapturedTaxRate

Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").Page("micclass:=Page").Link("html id:=ui-id-1", "innerhtml:=Enter").Click

Next
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Page("micclass:=Browser") this is wrong. An Object of type Page cannot be of Type Browser as well. (micclass is the type of the Object)

For identifying Pages simply use index:=0 if you do not want to use them in the Object Repository hierarchy